# Custom Legend Mapview

Tags: r, leaflet, sf, mapview

I want to add a really simple legend to my `mapview`-map. I have a `sfc_MULTILINESTRING`-object called path and a `sfc_POINT`-object called places. I just wanted to have a legend that shows a line and says "path" and a point that says "Points of Interest". I dont really know how I could implement this in mapview. The bit of code at the moment looks like this:

```
mapview::mapview(path, lwd = 7) + mapview(places)
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine your two shapes into a list, then name them with layer.name. This is listed in their [advanced section of documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/mapview_02-advanced.html)

```
mapview(list(path,places),
        layer.name = c("path","Points of Interest"))
```